# Парсниг записей со стены в вк сообществах

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Написал парсер сообщества (URL и текст записей приходят как надо) Необходимо выполнять парсинг не одной группы, а 200 групп. Как это можно реализовать?

Вот код:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os


def post_date():
    token = "Мой токен"
    version = 5.131
    domain = "группа"
    count_post = 200
    filter_post = "suggests"
    offset = 0

    response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get',
                            params={
                                'access_token': token,
                                'v': version,
                                'domain': domain,
                                'count': count_post,
                                'offset': offset
                            })
    data = response.json()
    items = data["response"]["items"]
    for item in items:
        text_post = item.get("text").strip()
        url_sec = str(item['from_id']) + '_' + str(item['id'])
        url = f"https://vk.com/studentkazani?w=wall{url_sec}"
        print(f"{url}\n {text_post}")


def main():
    post_date()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: У вас проблемы с циклами?

Comment: @СергейШ Не понимаю как это оформить

Comment: в цикле на каждой интеракций меняете нужную вам группу.

Comment: @СергейШ Можете пожалуйста написать код пример? Как именно менять (глупые вопрос наверное но я только учусь)

Comment: В данный момент у вас есть код, который парсит одну группу. Почему бы это не превратить в функцию и парсить 200 групп по разным id? // Изучите получше питон (в интернете есть множество курсов и разных книжек) и после задавайте чуть более конкретные вопросы.

Comment: @mironovmeow спасибо за ответ

Comment: @mironovmeow Мне только не понятно куда запрос втыкать и стоит ли в него передавать параметры или нет. Я не просил написать его за меня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

код пример:

```
def post_date(domain):
    print(domain)


for x in ('групп 1', 'групп 2'):
    post_date(x)
```